# Как считать тхт файл блоками

Tags: c#

Как возможно многопоточно считать тхт файл кусками то есть первый поток считывает, к примеру первые 100 строк(строки = длинны) второй считывает дальше 150 строк, и потом снова первый считывает дальше 50 строк после 250 строк(100-та и 150-ти)...есть какой нить вариант, как реализовать алгоритм?
Ладна считать это не проблема....проблема в том чтобы обратно верутся к первому потоку и чтобы он считал дальше строки которые начинаются после второго потока.

Comment: не параллелится работа с файлами, точнее это не имеет смысла, т.к. диск - устройство последовательного доступа безотносительно механика или ssd/flash, sata/sas или ide/scsi, логика интерфейса у него последовательная. Если уж сильно хочется, откройте файл на чтение без блокировки, и читайте один и тот же в разных потоках, каждый из своего стрима, только скорости это не прибавит, скорее наоборот

Comment: лучше опишите чего вы хотите добиться таким решением, может есть другое.

Comment: @rdorn это та я могу реализовать, там все просто, а вот то что я написал, посложнее, наверно----е, ну с клавы ввел что-то и пусть многопоточно комп ищет строку в массиве, типа того..

Comment: так в массиве или файле?

Comment: файл как массив, типа string []file=File.ReadAlllLines(@"\\\*.txt");

Comment: тогда смотри первый комментарий. Многопоточность не поможет. Только хуже будет и диск замучаете, если механика

Comment: то есть просто настругать потоков, и в каждом потоке прописать отдельно от и до ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55602/discussion-between-rdorn-and-tode).

Comment: @rdorn написал примерно так, и норма вышла)

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines_number = 100;
        var stroki = File.ReadLines(@"D:\data.txt").Take(lines_number).ToArray();
```